# The method abortBroadcast() is undefined for the type SMSReceiver

Tags: android, google-maps, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager, android-broadcast

I am trying to develop a simple location tracker. But, I am getting the following error:
`The method abortBroadcast() is undefined for the type SMSReceiver`. I am unable to figure it out. The line where I am getting this error is `this.abortBroadcast`. Please, help me out with this.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.whereareyou;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
public class SMSReceiver {
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    String senderTel;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle= intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs= null;
        String str="";
        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            senderTel="";
            Object[] pdus=(Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs= new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for(int i=0; i<msgs.length;i++)
            {
                msgs[i]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                if(i==0)
                {
                    senderTel=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                }
                str+=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }
            if(str.startsWith("where are you?"))
            {
                lm=(LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationListener= new MyLocationListener();
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 1000, locationListener);
                this.abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
        {
            if(loc!=null)
            {
                SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(senderTel, null, "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + loc.getLatitude() + "," + loc.getLongitude(), null, null);
                lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You are calling the function `abortBroadcast()`, but where it's defined?

Comment: i think abortBroadcast() method is a pre-defined method. its not a user defined method. its defined in BroadcastReceiver class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `abortBroadcast()` in `BroadcastReceiver` like that way, the class `SMSReceiver` should extend `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```